# Very slow artifactory query language

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I've been trying to implement a artifact cleanup process based on https://www.jfrog.com/blog/advanced-cleanup-using-artifactory-query-language-aql/ ... but found that the AQL is *really* slow.  i've seen queries still running after 24 hours with the server pinned at 100% cpu.

Using simple curl :

```
time curl -vv -u user:password -d "${query}" "http://server:8081/artifactory/api/search/aql"
```

I've measured :

```
items.find({"repo" : "ep-snapshots", "@milestone.keep": {"$ne" : "true"}, "@milestone.complete": {"$ne" : "true"}, "created": {"$before" : "3d"}}).limit(100)
```

33 minutes

```
items.find({"repo" : "ep-snapshots", "@milestone.keep": {"$ne" : "true"}, "@milestone.complete": {"$ne" : "true"}}).limit(100)
```

42 minutes

```
items.find({"repo" : "ep-snapshots", "@milestone.keep": {"$ne" : "true"}, "@milestone.complete": "false"}).limit(100)
```

574 minutes

Are there any techniques to investigate the performance of AQL ?  Anything obviously broken with the above ?

Thanks,

Pete